# How can I create a custom installation disk?

Tags: system-installation, iso

Ubuntu and Kubuntu don't come with additional applications such as Java, WINE, Dictionary etc.

I know that can download these applications from the Software Center, but it costs time and money. Internet isn't free and not everyone has access to high speed internet. Also, the Software Center's server is often busy and we cannot download with high speed and sometimes there are errors.

So, once I've gone to the trouble of installing all the programs I want in Kubuntu, how can I create an installation DVD to use it in the future when I want to reinstall it? I want to save time and cost to avoid re-downloading software from internet and give this installation disk to my friends.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons for a JAVA and WINE not being available by default in Ubuntu CD. First, for java, there is always an option for users to choose between OpenJDK and Sun's JDK.
A difference is presented in the following website:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977238/why-should-i-use-the-oracle-jdk-over-the-openjdk-or-vice-versa

Regarding WINE, Wine is particularly for those willing to run windows program on their ubuntu flavors. While many use it for games, others are just happy with the fact that ubuntu is the only OS booting their machine and might never use WINE. Alot of alternative applications like GIMP, Audacity, OpenShot, would happily replace Adobe Photoshop and other popular applications in windows.

Next, there is a stuff called AptOnCD available in following link:
http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/
once you have the software, you can easily create a backup of your current installations and use it for future. You can use the following link of a How-to on aptonCD:
http://www.howtogeek.com/110034/how-to-back-up-restore-your-installed-ubuntu-packages-with-aptoncd/

I would suggest you go for Ubuntu Studio: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Studio#Software_included

which comes with a lots of softwares regarding audio, video and other stuffs.
You can download it from its official website: http://ubuntustudio.org/

However, the stuffs packed in nearly 700 Mib of our lovely Ubuntu CD doesn't need any dependency on JAVA and WINE for their installation.

Hope this helps.
Regards, WinuxUser